# Как сослаться на конкретную точку отсчета при нахождении угла между тремя точками?

Tags: python

Ниже приведенный код исправно показывает угол между красной и оранжевой линиями, т.к. получает координаты двух крайних точек и ссылается на координаты 0, 0 как на "среднюю" точку.
Нужно заставить показывать угол между синей и зеленой линиями, для этого необходимо вместо 0, 0 ссылаться на "среднюю" точку 200, 200, и вот тут непонятно, как это сделать.

В поисковике много инфы со сложными объяснениями и километровыми формулами нахождения угла между тремя точками, но в моём случае угол уже считается, проблема только в принудительном назначении точки отсчета, решение которой найти не удалось

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

root = Tk()
root.geometry(f"{400}x{400}+{600}+{250}")

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=400)
canvas.pack()

xm = 0
ym = 0

def reaction():
    root.bind('<Motion>', move)

def move(event):
    global xm, ym
    xm = event.x
    ym = event.y
    crt_ln()

def crt_ln():
    x1 = 200
    y1 = 200
    x2 = xm
    y2 = ym
    canvas.delete("ld1")
    canvas.delete("ld2")
    canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='green', tags='ld1')
    canvas.create_line(0, 0, x2, y2, fill='orange', tags='ld2')


    v1 = Vector(400, 200)
    v2 = Vector(x2, y2)

    v1_theta = math.atan2(v1.y, v1.x)
    v2_theta = math.atan2(v2.y, v2.x)

    r = (v2_theta - v1_theta) * (180.0 / math.pi)

    if r < 0:
        r % 360

    print(int(r))

canvas.create_line(200, 200, 400, 200, fill='blue')
canvas.create_line(0, 0, 400, 200, fill='red')

reaction()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: подсказка]

Comment: пока что у вас все линии "прозрачного цвета". не пробовали попытаться приложить картинку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо нормализовать вектор. Вектор АВ состоящий из двух точек, например А(3, 7) и В(4, 2) находиться по формуле AB(Xb-Xa, Yb-Ya) и будет равен AB(4-3, 2-7) = AB(1, -5)

```
from tkinter import *
import math

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


root = Tk()
root.geometry(f"{400}x{400}+{600}+{250}")

canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=400)
canvas.pack()

def reaction():
    root.bind('<Motion>', move)

def move(event):
    crt_ln(event.x, event.y)


def crt_ln(xm, ym):
    x1 = y1 = 200
    red_vector = Vector(400-0, 200-0)
    blue_vector = Vector(400-200, 200-200)
    green_vector = Vector(xm-x1, ym-y1)
    orange_vector = Vector(xm-0, ym-0)

    canvas.delete("ld1")
    canvas.delete("ld2")
    canvas.create_line(x1, y1, xm, ym, fill='green', tags='ld1')
    canvas.create_line(0, 0, xm, ym, fill='orange', tags='ld2')

    red_theta = math.atan2(red_vector.y, red_vector.x)
    blue_theta = math.atan2(blue_vector.y, blue_vector.x)
    green_theta = math.atan2(green_vector.y, green_vector.x)
    orange_theta = math.atan2(orange_vector.y, orange_vector.x)

    grad_red_and_orange_vector = math.degrees(orange_theta - red_theta)
    grad_blue_and_green_vector = math.degrees(blue_theta - green_theta)

    print(f"alfa = {int(grad_red_and_orange_vector)}, beta = {int(grad_blue_and_green_vector)}")


canvas.create_line(200, 200, 400, 200, fill='blue')
canvas.create_line(0, 0, 400, 200, fill='red')

reaction()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ответ принят